# How to help different C(++) compilers to generate clean SIMD code?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, simd, llvm-clang

I've been experimenting a bit with different compilers to see how much they can be used to write efficient SIMD code (aarch64 and x64) without ugly intrinsics or hand-written asm.  And so far only Clang seems to do a correct job for aarch64. I think I might be missing some compiler hints or compilation flags.

I've tried to use `__restrict` keyword and I used the following compilation flags on GCC and Clang:

```
-force-vector-width=8 -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize
```

Here is the code:

```
typedef union
{
    float  coords[3];
    struct { float x; float y; float z; };

} vec3; // simple 3D vector

vec3 AddVectors(vec3 a, vec3 b)
{
    vec3 x = { { a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z } };

    return x;
}

void Add4Vectors(vec3* __restrict a, vec3* __restrict b)
{
    a[0] = AddVectors(a[0], b[0]);
    a[1] = AddVectors(a[1], b[1]);
    a[2] = AddVectors(a[2], b[2]);
    a[3] = AddVectors(a[3], b[3]);
}

void Add16Vectors(vec3* __restrict a, vec3* __restrict b)
{
    Add4Vectors(a, b);
    Add4Vectors(a + 4, b + 4);
    Add4Vectors(a + 8, b + 8);
    Add4Vectors(a + 12, b + 12);
}

void Add64Vectors(vec3* __restrict a, vec3* __restrict b)
{
    Add16Vectors(a, b);
    Add16Vectors(a + 16, b + 16);
    Add16Vectors(a + 32, b + 32);
    Add16Vectors(a + 48, b + 48);
}
```

You can toy with on on GodBolt.org
https://godbolt.org/z/SW3aH-

Here is the result I get from clang 8 (flags: -O3 -target aarch64)

```
AddVectors(vec3, vec3):                  // @AddVectors(vec3, vec3)
        fadd    s0, s0, s3
        fadd    s1, s1, s4
        fadd    s2, s2, s5
        ret
Add4Vectors(vec3*, vec3*):               // @Add4Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        ldp     q0, q1, [x0]
        ldp     q2, q3, [x1]
        ldr     q4, [x0, #32]
        ldr     q5, [x1, #32]
        fadd    v0.4s, v0.4s, v2.4s
        fadd    v1.4s, v1.4s, v3.4s
        fadd    v2.4s, v4.4s, v5.4s
        stp     q0, q1, [x0]
        str     q2, [x0, #32]
        ret
Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*):              // @Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        ldp     q0, q1, [x0]
        ldp     q2, q3, [x1]
        ldp     q4, q5, [x0, #32]
        ldp     q6, q7, [x1, #32]
        ldp     q16, q17, [x0, #64]
        ldp     q18, q19, [x1, #64]
        ldp     q20, q21, [x0, #96]
        ldp     q22, q23, [x1, #96]
        fadd    v0.4s, v0.4s, v2.4s
        fadd    v1.4s, v1.4s, v3.4s
        ldp     q2, q3, [x0, #128]
        fadd    v4.4s, v4.4s, v6.4s
        fadd    v5.4s, v5.4s, v7.4s
        ldp     q6, q7, [x1, #128]
        fadd    v16.4s, v16.4s, v18.4s
        fadd    v17.4s, v17.4s, v19.4s
        ldp     q18, q19, [x0, #160]
        fadd    v20.4s, v20.4s, v22.4s
        fadd    v21.4s, v21.4s, v23.4s
        ldp     q22, q23, [x1, #160]
        fadd    v2.4s, v2.4s, v6.4s
        fadd    v3.4s, v3.4s, v7.4s
        stp     q0, q1, [x0]
        fadd    v6.4s, v18.4s, v22.4s
        fadd    v7.4s, v19.4s, v23.4s
        stp     q4, q5, [x0, #32]
        stp     q16, q17, [x0, #64]
        stp     q20, q21, [x0, #96]
        stp     q2, q3, [x0, #128]
        stp     q6, q7, [x0, #160]
        ret
Add64Vectors(vec3*, vec3*):              // @Add64Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        stp     x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!   // 8-byte Folded Spill
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #16]     // 8-byte Folded Spill
        add     x29, sp, #16            // =16
        mov     x19, x1
        mov     x20, x0
        bl      Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        add     x0, x20, #192           // =192
        add     x1, x19, #192           // =192
        bl      Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        add     x0, x20, #384           // =384
        add     x1, x19, #384           // =384
        bl      Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp, #16]     // 8-byte Folded Reload
        add     x0, x20, #576           // =576
        add     x1, x19, #576           // =576
        ldp     x20, x19, [sp], #32     // 8-byte Folded Reload
        b       Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
```

This is pretty neat if you ask me, especially the Add16Vectors routine, I do not think I would write
a better version by hand.

But still, something is bugging me with the Add64Vectors routine.
The registers save on the stack does not seem necessary.
And it does not seem to be complicated at all for the compiler to avoid this, there is plenty of free registers.

Here is how I would write it:
Am I missing something?

```
Add64Vectors(vec3*, vec3*):             
        mov     x3, x1
        mov     x2, x0
        bl      Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        add     x0, x2, #192           
        add     x1, x3, #192           
        bl      Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        add     x0, x2, #384           
        add     x1, x3, #384           
        bl      Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
        add     x0, x2, #576           
        add     x1, x3, #576           
        b       Add16Vectors(vec3*, vec3*)
```

Now, I am a bit nitpicking with this, but here is the ugly part.

I do not want to post a too long message here, so please try this on your side to see the results. (on https://godbolt.org)
But the aarch64 version produced by Clang is the only where I think the compiler is doing a good job.

GCC (8.2) for ARM64 is using about twice as many instructions for the same routines MSVC for ARM64 is even worse.

But maybe this is because of the target not being as mainstream as x64?
Nope.

Results for x64 are appalling, and even if Clang seems to also be the winner here, I do not understand why the x64 version is twice as long
as the aarch64 version...

I am thinking of alignment issues or missing compilation flags, maybe?

Comment: OpenMP has a bunch of simd-related options that can give hints for vectorizing loops. And properly aligning arrays and informing the compiler about it is important (and is one of those hints)

Comment: Possible XY problem: Generally things like `vec3` (using a single SIMD vectors to hold a single geometry vector) doesn't vectorize well.  In this case it *could* for vertical add, if compilers can see past struct boundaries.  But unless you need this format, it's usually recommended to use separate arrays of x[], y[], and z[].  See https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/ for an intro to SIMD that explains this.  You might be constrained by other factors, though, so upvoted the question.